# An application of the martingal convergence theorem on a special product of i.i.d. uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm stuck on the following exercise and would appreciate any help:
Let $(X_n)$ be independent random variables which are uniformly distributed on the interval (0,2). Let
$$Y_k = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(X_k) \enspace \text{and} \enspace \mathcal{F}_n= \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$$
with $Y_0=1$ and $\mathcal{F}_0= \lbrace\varnothing,\Omega\rbrace$. Use martingales for the following:
Show that there is $q>1$ such that $q^n \sqrt{Y_n}$ converges almost surely to a finite random variable.
Because of $q>1$, I already tried to do a $ln(\cdot)$ transformation and proved it is a supermartingal, but the expectations were not bounded in that case. And there I'm now.

Comment: Im sorry, you are right. They have to be iid.

Comment: Was that to be $\sqrt[q]{Y_n}$, or did you intend what is written (namely, $q\sqrt{Y_n}$.)?

In any event, $(Y_n)$ is a non-negative martingale, which might be useful.

Comment: No it was meant to be $q \sqrt{Y_n}$. Can you concretize what you mean by using that $Y_n$ is a nonnegative martingale? (It is obviously the case though)

Comment: I now got a mail from the prof, that q was wrong and instead it has to be q^n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_n(q):= q^n\sqrt{Y_n}$. If we can find $q>1$ such that $(M_n(q))$ is a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal F_n)$, then we will be done, as $M_n(q)$ will be a non-negative martingale bounded in $\mathbb L^1$.

To find $q$, we can compute $\mathbb E\left[M_n(q)\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}\right]$ by using the pull-out property and independence. In order to find $M_{n-1}(q)$, we need $q$ such that $q\mathbb E\left[\sqrt{X_n}\right]=1$.